# C# MVC - Generic Wizard Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to make form wizard, where I could define steps. For each step I need to have contoller and view based on a type of step. I tried to do it on generic types, but I have problem with running method on controller which is generic.

Here is example.

```
public interface IExampleInterface { }
public abstract class WizardBaseController<T> : Controller where T : IExampleInterface
{
    public abstract List<T> Steps { get; set; }
    public abstract ActionResult RenderStep(T step);

    public virtual ActionResult RenderNext(T step)
    {
        var index = Steps.IndexOf(step);
        return RenderStep(Steps[index+1]);
    }
}

public class ExampleClass : IExampleInterface { }
public class WizardController<T> : WizardBaseController<ExampleClass> where T : ExampleClass
{
    public override List<ExampleClass> Steps { get; set; }

    public override ActionResult RenderStep(ExampleClass step)
    {
        //do stuff
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual ActionResult RenderStep(T step)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ActionResult CreateSteps()
    {
        Steps = new List<ExampleClass>
        {
            new AnotherExampleClassA(),
            new AnotherExampleClassB(),
            new ExampleClass(),
            new AnotherExampleClassB(),
            new AnotherExampleClassA(),
        };

        return RenderNext(Steps.First());
    }
}

public class AnotherExampleClassA : ExampleClass { }
public class ChildWizzardConotroller : WizardController<AnotherExampleClassA>
{
    public override ActionResult RenderStep(AnotherExampleClassA e)
    {
        //do stuff
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class AnotherExampleClassB : ExampleClass { }
public class AnotherChildWizzardConotroller : WizardController<AnotherExampleClassB>
{
    public override ActionResult RenderStep(AnotherExampleClassB e)
    {
        //do stuff
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

but when I try to call action from wizardController I'm receiving 404 error

```
<a href="@Url.Action("CreateSteps", "Wizard")">Trigger Action</a>
```

Im not sure, if my way for doing it is correct.

Basicly my goal is to create wizard with differennt types of steps and call different methods based on a type of steps. For example for calling method RenderStep(with a parameter type - ExampleClass) I want to call method which is in WizardController, 
when RenderStep(with a parameter type -  AnotherExampleClassA) to call method in ChildWizzardConotroller etc.